# Programmatically Exporting Reports via SSRS API

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services

I have a custom interface where my users select multiple reports and export them all at once. I need to programatically export these reports and preferably offer all the same format options. I understand this can be done through the SSRS API. Does anyone already know how to do this to save me some research time?

Many thanks...

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you would use the [ReportExecutionService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164418%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx) class - not the management API, which is where I was looking at first.

Use the [Render](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/microsoft.wssux.reportingserviceswebservice.rsexecutionservice2005.reportexecutionservice.render%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx) method to generate the report.  Pay attention to those first two parameters of Render to specify the format.

Hope this helps.