# TFS - automation of the compare task

Tags: sql, reporting-services, tfs, ssis

Do you have any idea how to achieve the follow? I would like to do a comparison between what is currently stored in the TFS and the live version of SSRS reports, SSIS packages, SQL stored procedures/table definitions....

It could look like that for SSRS reports:
1. Extract definition of the report
2. Add this to TFS
3. Run a comparison between the previous and the current version of the report.
4. Send/store the report with differences

How can I achieve that automatically, I was thinking about using TFS API, but not sure where to start.

Thank you for your help,
Rafal

Answer (score 0):

There is a way through [ReportExecutionService Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164418(v=SQL.90).aspx) to generate reports using the TFS API and SSRS.

> Provided that a web service reference was added to the project
>   already, this will generate a file with the given parameters. Here the
>   start and end dates are provided as parameters and the report is
>   generated using the [Render()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/microsoft.wssux.reportingserviceswebservice.rsexecutionservice2005.reportexecutionservice.render(v=SQL.90).aspx) method.  Source [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12307931/generate-reports-programmatically-using-the-tfs-api-and-ssrs)

```
private void GenerateReport()
  {
    ReportExecutionService rs = new ReportExecutionService();
    rs.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
    rs.Url = "http://<TFS server name>/reportserver/ReportExecution2005.asmx";

   // Render arguments
   byte[] result = null;
   tring reportPath = @"<SSRS report path>";
   string format = "PDF";
   string historyID = null;
   string devInfo = @"<DeviceInfo><Toolbar>False</Toolbar></DeviceInfo>";

   // Prepare report parameter.
    ParameterValue[] parameters = new ParameterValue[2];
    parameters[0] = new ParameterValue();
    parameters[0].Name = "StartDateParam";
    parameters[0].Value = "2016-05-01 00:00:00";
    parameters[1] = new ParameterValue();
    parameters[1].Name = "EndDateParam";
    parameters[1].Value = "2016-05-30 00:00:00";
    parameters[2] = new ParameterValue();
    parameters[2].Name = "AreaParam";
    parameters[2].Value = "[Work Item].[Area Hierarchy].[All]";
    parameters[3] = new ParameterValue();
    parameters[3].Name = "WorkItemTypeParam";
    parameters[3].Value = "[Work Item].[System_WorkItemType].&[Task]";
    parameters[4] = new ParameterValue();
    parameters[4].Name = "StateParam";
    parameters[4].Value = "[Work Item].[System_State].&[Active]";
    parameters[5] = new ParameterValue();
    parameters[5].Name = "TrendLineParam";
    parameters[5].Value = "both";

   DataSourceCredentials[] credentials = null;
    string showHideToggle = null;
    string encoding;
    string mimeType;
    string extension;
    Warning[] warnings = null;
    ParameterValue[] reportHistoryParameters = null;
    string[] streamIDs = null;

   ExecutionInfo execInfo = new ExecutionInfo();
    ExecutionHeader execHeader = new ExecutionHeader();

   rs.ExecutionHeaderValue = execHeader;

   execInfo = rs.LoadReport(reportPath, historyID);

   var parameters_ = rs.GetExecutionInfo().Parameters;

  rs.SetExecutionParameters(parameters, "en-us"); 
    String SessionId = rs.ExecutionHeaderValue.ExecutionID;

   Console.WriteLine("SessionID: {0}", rs.ExecutionHeaderValue.ExecutionID);

   try
    {
        result = rs.Render(format, devInfo, out extension, out encoding, out mimeType, out warnings, out streamIDs);

  execInfo = rs.GetExecutionInfo();

   Console.WriteLine("Execution date and time: {0}", execInfo.ExecutionDateTime);

   }
    catch (SoapException e)
   {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Detail.OuterXml);
   }
   // Write the contents of the report to an MHTML file.
   try
   {
       FileStream stream = File.Create("report.pdf", result.Length);
        Console.WriteLine("File created.");
        stream.Write(result, 0, result.Length);
        Console.WriteLine("Result written to the file.");
        stream.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }

}
```

After the report generated, you just need to check them into TFS server. Then you just need to use `Difference.DiffFiles` method which compares two files using the internal diff engine, and return the linked list of DiffSegments. More details, please refer this [MSDN blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mohamedg/2009/03/08/how-to-diff-files-using-tfs-apis/).

Comment: Thank you Patrick for your answer, but it is not for I was asking for. I want to compare automatically the source of the report (.rdl file) stored on the SSRS server with what is currently checked in in the TFS.

Comment: Why you just want to compare two files? For your situation, there is a diff window in VS to clearly see the difference between two files  or two versions of the same file. https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/compare-files  About how to diff files using TFS API, please refer this blog: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mohamedg/2009/03/08/how-to-diff-files-using-tfs-apis/

Comment: Because I would like to schedule that on weekly/monthly basis to check if what is in SSRS/SSIS/SQL is the same as in TFS and if not investigate that. There are few people working on different things and they not always follow the process correctly.